# Cómo validar el valor XML con el valor que se muestra en una columna de una tabla

Tags: javascript, php, xml

Estoy tratando de validar un valor que estoy leyendo de un XML, la validación que quiero realizar es comparar el valor que estoy leyendo del XML con el valor que se muestra en la tabla, esta validación se debe hacer al cargar un XML archivo, es decir que al momento de cargar el archivo XML lea el valor del XML que quiero comparar con el valor de la columna en la tabla, si estos valores son correctos permita que se cargue el archivo XML de lo contrario mostrar alguna alerta.

Hasta ahora estoy obteniendo el valor que quiero comparar en una tabla para este caso lo vamos a llamar `NIT`, para obtener los datos hago uso de un procedimiento de almacenamiento en SQL, obtengo dos valores `NumRegister` y `NIT`, pero aquí el único que me interesa validar es `NIT`, el código para obtener los datos de la tabla es el siguiente:

**showdata.php**

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$param = $_POST['param'];  
    switch($param) {
        case '1':
              $query = array();
                include './db/connect.php';
                $USER = utf8_encode($_POST['idUser']);
                $sql = "{call StoreProcedureTest(?)}";
                $params = array($USER);
                $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params);
                
                if ( $stmt === false) {
                    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
                }
                

                $query = [];
                $query1 = [];

                $lastRegister = '';
                $lastRegister1 = '';
                
                while( $row1 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt1) ) {
                    $record1 = array(
                        "Register"  => $row1['Register']
                        
                    );
                    array_push($query1, $record1);
                }
                
                while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt) ) {
                    
                    if(strcmp($lastRegister, $row['NumRegister']) != 0) {

                    $query[] = [
                        "NumRegister"       => $row['NumRegister'],
                        "NIT"               => $row['Nit']                                 
                    ];
                    
                }
                $index = count($query) - 1;
                if($index < 0) {
                    die('Error: No avalaible');
                }
                
                }
                sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);       
                sqlsrv_close($conn);
                $json = [
                    "success"=> count($query) > 0 ? true : false,
                    "data"=>$query
                ];
                echo json_encode($json);
     
        break;

}


?>
```

Adicional como comentario estoy haciendo uso de la librería Datatables la cual utilizo para mostrar los datos obtenidos anteriormente en una tabla, lo cual hago a través de una función en javascript, para esto he desarrollado la siguiente función en javascript:

**tablelist.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#example').dataTable( {
        responsive : true,
         ajax : {
             "type": 'POST',
             "url" : './Showdata.php',  
             "dataType": 'JSON',             
             "cache": false,
            "data": {
                 'param' : 1,              
             },
         },
         columns: [          
             {
                 "className":      'details-control',
                 "orderable":      false,
                 "data":           null,
                 "defaultContent": ''
             },
             { "data" : "NumRegister" },
             { "data" : "NIT" },                  
        ],
         order : [[1, 'desc']],
    } );
```

Para leer el archivo de nodo XML que necesito validar y que corresponde `NIT`, destaco lo siguiente en otro script PHP:

**readxml.php**

```
$NitNumber = (string)$xml->children('cfdi',true)->Receiver[0]->attributes()['NIT'];
```

En el mismo script PHP para cargar el archivo XML que tendré que validar con lo comentado anteriormente y que además luego de su carga exitosa se almacena en una ubicación, estoy haciendo uso del siguiente código:

```
$fileXML = $_FILES['XmlToUpload']['name'];
$pathXML = "//FILEALL/XML/";


if(move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['XmlToUpload']['tmp_name'], $pathXML . $fileXML)){
echo 'Upload Success';  
}
```

Entonces, en resumen, lo que necesito validar es el valor que estoy leyendo en el XML que se asigna a la variable `$NitNumber` con el valor que se muestra en la tabla como menciono al comienzo de mi pregunta, ¿hay algo adicional que deba completar esta validación?

**Actualización 1:**

Para avanzar un poco en la solución de este problema he decidido agregar un botón en la tabla donde me muestra los datos que estoy obteniendo del store procedure, este botón me abrirá una ventana modal que contendrá una etiqueta que mostrará el valor que quiero validar con el XML y, además, esta ventana también contendrá un botón de carga de archivos XML.

El código que utilicé para mostrar la ventana modal es el siguiente:

```
<!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" id="ModalUploadXML" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" >
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle" style="color: #FFFFFF;">ADD XML</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true" style="color: #FFFFFF;">&times;</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="lblNit" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Nit Company:</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtNitCompany" disabled>
                        </div>
                     </div>

       <form action="" id="uploadform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <div class="form-group row">
                        <label for="fileToUpload" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">File XML:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="XmlToUpload" class="btn" accept=".xml" onchange="ValidateFiles(), validation()" required="">
              </div>
          </div>
    
        </div>        

          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Back</button>
            <button type="button" id="upload" class="btn btn-success" value="submit" disabled onclick="clickSend(this)">Upload File</button>
          </div>
      </form>

            </div>
      <div class="upload-msg"></div>
          </div>
</div>
```

Si se fijan bien la etiqueta en la que quiero mostrar el `Nit` desde el store procedure corresponde a `txtNitCompany`, la cual estoy intentando mostrar pero me indica que se encuentra `undefined`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mi archivo tablelist.js le he asignado en una variable global el valor de la etiqueta `txtNitCompany` de la siguiente manera:

```
var NitCompanyG = $("#txtNitCompany").val();
```

Donde posteriormente en mi archivo ReadXml.php le he enviado por POST la variable `NITValue` a la etiqueta `txtNitCompany` de la siguiente manera:

```
$NITValue= $_POST["txtNitCompany "];
```

Para luego realizar la validación de comparar el valor del archivo XML con el valor de la etiqueta, esto lo tengo de la siguiente manera haciendo uso del código que agregue al inicio de la pregunta solo que esta vez le agrego la validación:

```
if($NITNumber == $NITValue){

$fileXML = $_FILES['XmlToUpload']['name'];
$pathXML = "//FILEALL/XML/";


    if(move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['XmlToUpload']['tmp_name'], $pathXML . $fileXML)){
    echo 'Upload Success';  
    }
}
```

He llegado a este punto pero con una variable `undefined`, algo que deba agregar para evitar la variable `undefined`?

Comment: porque lo tienes en disabled?  --> `<input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtNitCompany" disabled>`  Eso quizás está provocando el undefined

Comment: Necesitas una llamada ajax para recuperar el valor de la tabla de base de datos (eso ya esta en tablelist.js). Necesitas otra llamada ajax para recuperar el valor del xml: creo que lo que colocaste en readxml.php debe ir en el mismo archivo donde subiste el archivo FILE y este responder con el valor leido del xml. Una vez que tengas esas dos respuestas en javascript puedes hacer la comparación que deseas.